# Razor forms are generating a different Html Id than expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razorengine

I am using MVC Core 1.1 with Razor and binding it to a ViewModel which has a property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[Display(Name = "Surname")]
public string Surname { get; set; }
```

In Razor, I am using the TextBoxFor to bind this as such:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Surname, new { @class = "required" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Surname)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now, if I run in **Debug** mode I am getting the Id and name "Surname" in the output HTML. However, on **Release** mode I am getting "SurName".

I tried cleaning and rebuilding and I still have the same results. I tried to see if I have some weird JS that is changing this on the client-side, but there isn't any.

Did anybody encounter a similar situation? Do you have any recommendation where to look?

Comment: Doesn't exist in the source code in the whole solution.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with .NET Core 2.0. What happens if you remove the Display attribute?